# C# VFP OLEDB connection string problems (DBF and CDX vs DBF and IDX)

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro, foxpro, oledbconnection

I've connected to foxpro databases before, but only ones that have both a .dbf and .idx file.

I register the Microsoft Ole DB Provider for Visual Foxpro 7.0 and use the following type of code:

```
  string sqlSTR = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
  string strConnect = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\Stuff.dbf;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"
```

And open the connection.  This file, though, has a .dbf and .cdx file (which, reading online seems to be the structure of the database).  When I use the connection string above and the following code:

```
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(strConnect);
myConn.Open()
```

It doesn't error or anything, but the execution of the program hangs here.  I have several other parts of the same program that are connecting to files with a dbf + idx file present (not cdx).  What am I doing wrong that I need to correct?

I use the sqlSTR for later operations using a data adapter btw.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any reference to dBase IV in the connection string is wrong. Try it without that part.

Comment: Actually the CDX file is an index file and not the structure of the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string is wrong. It should be like:

```
string sqlSTR = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
string strConnect = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=C:\;"
```

Using c:\ as a location for database files (or other files) is questionable.

Comment: @J W, Cetin is correct.  The issue is the connection should point to the PATH where the files are located, not the full name of the table you are querying.  I can only assume you simplified your connection to the root of C:\, but would otherwise be in some other path.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer for anyone that has the same problem.

The reference for dBase IV actually doesn't matter either way; it does for the older DBF+IDX combination of foxpro files and is needed (think early VFP or before VFP back in foxpro 2.0 days).

All I was really missing was the *.dbc, *.dct, and *.dcx files in the same directory that were also associated with it.  It threw me since these files were actually a different base filename than the Stuff.dbf/Stuff.cdx files.

I just used a try{}catch{} and put the exception to messagebox and it told me which (different named) file it was looking for.

Thanks for the help!